# If I run my project I run in error but if I run the project from terminal everything it's ok

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

If I run my project from terminal everything it's ok, but if I run the project from Spring Tool Suite I receive this error
[image]

The script that I use for running the project from terminal is this

```
./mvnw -P dev,casalibro-dev
```

and in the pom file I've setted this profile

```
<profile>
        <id>casalibro-dev</id>
        <properties>
            <datasource.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/casalibro</datasource.url>
            <datasource.username>casalibro</datasource.username>
            <datasource.password>xxxxxx</datasource.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Probably your maven repo is "confused". Delete your local maven repo and re-run the application using Maven and check if it still works, if it does not work that means that you are really missing the database library.

Comment: Is a Spring Boot app. I run the project as Spring Boot App

Comment: Anyway, delete your maven repo and try again, sometimes Spring-boot gets "confused" with the classpath

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how i delete maven repo? from pom?

Comment: I run this `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` from my project folder

Comment: Hey Dennis you can delete the folder manually, Google where is your folder for your OS, in Linux it is in ~/.m2/

Comment: Nothing, don't work

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the pom.xml file is to define the build of a project. If you want to define properties for the application itself, you should add an application.properties file to the resource section of your app and define your properties in there. Those properties will be part of your app and can be used at runtime.